# how to set common controller in group route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am working on **laravel** but i have no idea about using route.
i used route group method but i have a question that can we use a common controller in group route

like

I have bunch of routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'agent'], function(){
    Route::get('pay', 'PaymentController@pay');
    Route::get('pay/success', 'PaymentController@success');
    Route::get('pay/failure', 'PaymentController@failure');
    Route::get('credits', 'PaymentController@credits');
    Route::get('checkout', 'PaymentController@checkout');
});
```

As you can see they all are using same route so is there any way to make this as dry as possible i know those are small route but when it goes long line then it become hard to understand i know it's kind of stupid question

is there any attribute like

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'agent', 'controller' => 'PaymentController'], function(){
    Route::get('pay', 'pay');
    Route::get('pay/success', 'success');
    Route::get('pay/failure', 'failure');
    Route::get('credits', 'credits');
    Route::get('checkout', 'checkout');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't any option to define default controller for a route group. But if you have resource routes then it defines all the sub routes by itself, though it's limited to only CRUD routes. You can do something like this if you're interested.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'agent'], function($controller = 'TestController@') {
    Route::get('pay', $controller.'pay');
    Route::get('pay/success', $controller.'success');
    Route::get('pay/failure', $controller.'failure');
    Route::get('credits', $controller.'credits');
    Route::get('checkout', $controller.'checkout');
});
```

Comment: I appreciate you answer but this is not what i am looking for

Comment: @User97798 I answered with how it is, the code was just an example. The point is that there's no option at the moment to define the default controller for a route group. If you're interested you may lobby for this to be added with the laravel team on github.

Comment: i was totally got your point and agreed that there is not way to do that as you told in your answer. you cleared my question already